# Default Home Folder Permissions on CentOS 5

Tags: centos, permissions, home-directory

Whenever I create a new user in CentOS 5, their home folder is automatically given the UGO setting of "755", how can I change the default to "700"?

Also, the server is technically ClearOS, but it's based on CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You edit the file /etc/login.defs and change the umask value to:

```
UMASK 077
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `UMASK` in `/etc/login.defs` to 077:

```
#
# If useradd should create home directories for users by default
# On RH systems, we do. This option is overridden with the -m flag on
# useradd command line.
#
CREATE_HOME yes

# The permission mask is initialized to this value. If not specified, 
# the permission mask will be initialized to 022.
UMASK           077
```

Comment: ARGH! You beat me to it once again!